# Magento related, can I change the cron job time interval with something new from my database?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cron, time

For example, I got in config,

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <test>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>test/observer::saveAction</model>
            </run>  
        </test>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And at: `*/15 * * * *`, can I call a specific time from my db? I want to let the user choose the time interval for the update function. But I am not sure if I can call something from db using php in `config.xml`, is there a way to put the interval for a cron job in a php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a system configuration text field via `system.xml` and use it as your cron schedule**:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <test>
            <schedule>
                <config_path>path/to/system_config</config_path>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>test/observer::saveAction</model>
            </run>  
        </test>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Don't forget to **add a default value to this field** or it won't work if your customer don't change it:

```
<default>
    <path>
        <to>
            <system_config>*/15 * * * *</system_config>
        </to>
    </path>
</default>
```

Comment: Yes, but when the customer chose an interval, I will first save that interval to my db, and after that call the db value with the interval time and replace it in the cron schedule, but I will still not be able to call a value in the system.xml, right?

Comment: @DanteZ well system.xml fields are stored in the database right ? In core_config_data